# How does the wallet know that this seed phrase is generated before?

Tags: bitcoin-wallet-app

When I tried login using a random mnemonic phrase the wallet shows incorrect word? How does the wallet know that it is not previously generated?

Answer (score 2):

Seed phrases usually include a [checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum). For example, a 12-word [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) seed phrase has 4 checksum bits, which means only about 1 in 16 randomly typed seed phrases will be considered valid.